# Как запустить python скрипт, использующий speech_recognition в терминале на raspbian?

Tags: python-2.x, raspberry-pi, терминал, raspbian, распознавание-речи

Есть файл /home/pi/test.py:

```
import speech_recognition
print("ok")
```

Когда я запускаю его через IDLE все нормально работает. Если пытаюсь запустить в терминале:

```
sudo python /home/pi/test_.py
```

то получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/test_.py", line 1, in <module>
    import speech_recognition
ImportError: No module named speech_recognition
```

хотя модуль установлен. Я использую второй питон, система raspbian.

Answer (score 0):

Если компьютер пишет, что модуль не установлен, он на самом деле не установлен. Компьютеры не врут. В отсутствии модуля можно убедиться, проверив наличие файла модуля в библиотеке python.

Возможные причины проблемы:

- Установлен модуль для python2, python запускает python3
- Установка модуля завершилась с ошибкой
- Модуль установлен локально для одного пользователя, используется для другого
- Сегодня несчастливый день